# SD card problem

Tags: sd-card

I have purchase raspberry pi with pre loaded NOOBS SD card.  On installation I select rasbian then it proceed to install it then it display successful installation when I click the ok sign then it went blank, after a while or on switching it off on, it display again the NOOBS for selection of os for installation but the result is the same.  I try fedora-arm-installer, the SD card do not have any image and only a corrupted image file. same with the dd command in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

> I have purchase raspberry pi with pre loaded NOOBS SD card. On installation I select rasbian then it proceed to install it then it display successful installation when I click the ok sign then it went blank, after a while or on switching it off on, it display again the NOOBS for selection of os for installation but the result is the same.

This is a shame and I suggest you report that to the people who sold you the pi and the card.   Obviously this is not what should happen, and exactly what went wrong may be impossible to say from afar.

> I try fedora-arm-installer, the SD card do not have any image and only a corrupted image file. same with the dd command in Linux.

You do not explain what you mean by "corrupted image file", so this a little difficult to diagnose as well.  Using `dd` from a linux machine should absolutely without doubt allow you to create a working image, so more information here would be helpful.  Right now, your question is, more or less, *"I followed all the instructions and it didn't work"*, which **is actually not a question, it is just a statement**, very much like, *"Hi, my car broke down mysteriously and I don't know why."* Neither does anyone reading such a statement -- how could they?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the people who sold it to him messed it up?

Comment: No, but they did *sell* it to him (for money) and should either take it back if he feels it doesn't work, or demonstrate that it does work.

Comment: agreed. Just wanted to know if you knew the exact problem though.